# How to hide a h:outputLink conditionally?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

How can I hide a `h:ouputLink` based on a boolean in the backing bean?

For disabling I'd to it like this:

```
<h:commandButton disabled="#{backing.property}" />
```

But how can I hide completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

```
<h:commandButton id="myComponent" rendered="#{backing.property}" />
```

Sorry, my fault. You were searching for h:outputLink. Because both *h:outputLink* and *h:commandButton* derive from [UIComponentBase](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#isRendered%28%29), both derived classes have the method `isRendered()` and you do not need to wrap the commandLink in some sort of panel.

```
<h:outputLink rendered="#{backing.property}" />
```

**Update**

*myComponent* will be "hidden" due to because it will not be rendered.
Not to **render** *myComponent* means that you need to do an update (e.g. with an ajax request) on an UIComponent surrounding *myComponent*, like this:

```
<h:panelGrid id="myPanelGrid">
  ....
  <h:outputLink id="myComponent" rendered="#{backing.property}" />
  ....
<h:panelGrid>

<h:commandButton value="show" action="#{backing.setPropertyToTrueMethod}" update="myPanelGrid" />
```

see for API Specification: [JavaTM Platform, Enterprise Edition 6 API Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/)

Comment: Yes but I looked for `h:outputLink`. With your hint I found out that I can wrap a h:commandLink (or anything else) in a `h:panelGroup rendered=..`

Comment: That won't hide the component, it won't be rendered in the view. You should separate the terms. You should warn OP that in order to update (re-render) the component in the View (i.e. hiding and showing the link with an ajax request), the component should be wrapped by a UIContainer like `<h:panelGrid>` and you should update this UIContainer in order to show the link.